# Nonclustered indexes

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql, dmv

I have a question on index

Our Application is throwing the following SQL error

> Index 'INDEXNAME' on table 'dbo.TABLENAME' (specified in the FROM clause) does not exist. Error: Unknown Error Errorcode: 308

But when I queried the DMV I am able to see the index. Also, a particular column is used in two different non clustered indexes, is this a valid set up? Any suggestions to fix this issue.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you post the error exactly it is coming. Your question is not clear

Comment: The error message thrown is : Index 'INDEXNAME' on table 'dbo.TABLENAME' (specified in the FROM clause) does not exist.
  Error: Unknown Error Errorcode: 308

Comment: Can we have a single column being  a part of two non clustered indexes?

Comment: Yes you can have

Comment: Looks like you are using an index hint in a query. Do you really need that? Is the hint on the same table that the index is on?

Comment: Are you looking in the right database/instance?

Comment: yes it is on the same table

Comment: Any chance the database is case sensitive and the index is IndexName while the error is INDEXNAME?

Comment: can you post your entire select statement?